# how to make your tcsh command promt show LSF job count?

Tags: prompt, tcsh, platform-lsf

I want to monitor LSF job count through command `prompt`. `%j` will not give me the LSF job count. Can anyone tell how to configure command prompt to show the LSF job count?

Comment: What is LSF and what is %j?

Comment: By "job count", do you mean number of running jobs submitted by your account?  If yes, then you can use `bjobs -sum` and grep/awk out the RUN column.